# Issue with initializeApp() in firebase functions

Tags: android, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

i am getting warnings in firebase cloud functions log. the functions were deployed properly and was working before. now i am getting an error.

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.

I have spent 5 to 6 hours for searching solution then i tried one solution in which i have downloaded the the serviceAccountKey.json file and use that file but the i got an other error while deploying the functions. and i didn't find any solution yet. 
here is the error

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

ReferenceError: functions is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Parental Sheild\Coding\defenderFunctions\functions\index.js:22:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at C:\Users\H.A.R\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\H.A.R\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:38:3)
```

i have upgrade node to 8.12.0 and upgrade npm to latest version.

here the code of initializing App

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "https://database url"
});
```

here is my firebase function code

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/Defender/{UserId}/Child/{PinId}/Messages/{pushId}')
    .onWrite((change,context) => {
        const message = change.after.val();
        const sender = message.from;
        const receiver = message.to;
        const userID= message.uid;
        const promises = [];

        // if (senderUid == receiverUid) {
        //     //if sender is receiver, don't send notification
        //     promises.push(change.after.ref.remove());
        //     return Promise.all(promises);
        // }

        if (userID== receiver) {

                 const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Defender/${userID}/Profile/instanceId`).once('value');
                 const getSenderUidPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Defender/${userID}/Child/${sender}/Profile/name`).once('value');

            return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getSenderUidPromise]).then(results => {
            const instanceId = results[0].val();
            const sender = results[1].val();
            console.log('notifying ' + receiver + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + sender);

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: sender,
                    body: message.body,
                    sound: "default"
                    // icon: sender.photoURL
                }
            };

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });
        });

        }else{

                 const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Defender/${userID}/Child/${receiver}/Profile/instanceId`).once('value');
                 const getSenderUidPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Defender/${userID}/Profile/displayName`).once('value');

            return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise, getSenderUidPromise]).then(results => {
            const instanceId = results[0].val();
            const sender = results[1].val();
            console.log('notifying ' + receiver + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + sender);

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: sender,
                    body: message.body,
                    sound: "default"
                    // icon: sender.photoURL
                }
            };

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });
            });

        }

    });
```

**Update:** i have found the issue. i am reading data from database inside the function and getting error because i have secure rules on my firebase database. now i don't know how to solve this issue. any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to show all the relevant code.  Your error is occurring on line that's not shown here.

Comment: @DougStevenson i have updated the code. check it now

Comment: i have publish the simple function and that function is working fine. the issue is with the path to database.

Comment: i have found the issue. i am reading data from database inside the function and getting error because i have secure rules on my firebase database. now i don't know how to solve this issue. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `functions`, but you never apparently never defined it in your code.  You probably meant to require the `firebase-functions` at the top of your code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
```

Comment: yes i am doing that. i just missed to put it here. i am using that and still getting error

Comment: i think that error is with the dynamic path. because i changed the function with simple path then it was working.

Comment: Regardless, the error still is saying that you used a variable called "functions" without defining it first.

Comment: then what to do now?

Comment: i was missing the functions statement. i was commenting the line when i initialize App with admin. issue Resolved!!